# Edit default alert in subscribed calender

Tags: alert

I am currently subscribed to myasics ics running calender which shows my training plan. Its default alert is set to one week before.

I want to change that to two alerts. One being the day before and one on the day. I cant seem to edit this default.

How do I alter it?

Answer (score 1):

**On a Mac** running a current OS, this is how you would go about adding multiple alerts for one event.

[image]

- Double-click your event
- Click the date/time of the event
- Click the 'Alert' field and select when you would like your first alert
  to happen (notice that there is a 'custom' field)
- Now that you've selected a time period for your first alert, if you
  hover over the 'Alert' field you should see a small '+' symbol to the right; if you click it, it should trigger a second alert option.

**On an iPhone:**

- Locate your event and tap it to open it
- Click 'Edit' in the top right corner of the screen (**Note:** *If you don't click edit and instead only try to adjust the alert section from the main window, it will not give you the option to set up a second alert*.)
- Scroll down to the Alert section; choose the time frame for your
  first alert
- Now that you've set the first alert, you should see an option for
  'Second Alert' below the original 'Alert' option (**Note**: *The 'Second Alert' option doesn't look like it exists until you set up the first alert*)
- Choose a time frame for the second alert and then click 'Done' in the
  top right hand corner of the screen

Comment: Thanks but I'm on an iPad Pro and tapping on the event does not bring up an edit option anywhere.

Comment: Also on my iPhone 5 while I can change the default alert there is no edit option on the top right of my screen and therefore no 2nd alert option brought up.